# Find a string in one file and append part of it to matching line in another file

Tags: perl

I have two files

first:

8237764738;**00:78:9E:EE:CA:6F**;FTTH;MULTI
8237764738;2C:39:96:52:47:82;FTTH;MULTI
0415535921;**E8:BE:81:86:F1:6F**;FTTH;MULTI
0415535921;2C:39:96:5B:12:C6;EZ;SINGLE
...etc

second:

**00:78:9E:EE:CA:6F**;2013/10/28 13:37:50
**E8:BE:81:86:F1:6F**;2013/11/05 13:38:30
00:78:9E:EC:4A:B0;2013/10/28 13:59:16
2C:E4:12:AA:F7:95;2013/10/31 13:57:55
...etc

and I have to take mac_address (second position) from the first file and find it in the second one 
and append (if match) to first file the date at end from the second file.

output:

```
8237764738;00:78:9E:EE:CA:6F;FTTH;MULTI;2013/10/28 13:37:50   
0415535921;E8:BE:81:86:F1:6F;FTTH;MULTI;2013/11/05 13:38:30
```

I write a simple script to find the mac_address 
but I don't know how to put in the script to add the date.

```
my %iptv;
    my @result;
    open IN, "/home/terminals.csv";
    while (<IN>) {
        chomp;
        @wynik = split(/;/,$_);
        $iptv{$result[1]} = $result[0];
        }
    close IN;

    open IN, "/home/reboots.csv";
    open OUT, ">/home/out.csv";
    while (<IN>) {
        chomp;
        my ($mac, $date) = split(/;/,$_);
        if (defined $iptv{$mac})
        {
        print OUT "$date,$mac \n";
        }
    }
    close IN;
    close OUT;
```

Comment: I've read your description a couple of times and I can't quite make sense of it.  I understand that there are mac addresses in both files and that these match.  Do you simply want to add the data from the first file to the second matching on mac address?? Or is the first field in the first file some kind of encoded date?

Comment: can you show a sample of what the final output should be?

Comment: How big are these two files? Mere megabytes (or smaller), or gigabytes, or what? Are the MAC numbers in the first file unique, or could the same MAC number appear twice? Supposing a given MAC number appears more than once in the second file (they seem to be reboot times, and machines can be rebooted many times), which value should be printed with the data from the first?  Once for each match, or just the first, or just the last, or some other criterion?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first file lists each MAC number once and that you want an output line for each time the MAC appears in the second file, then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 terminals reboots\n" unless scalar(@ARGV) == 2;

my %iptv;
open my $in1, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Failed to open file $ARGV[0] for reading";
while (<$in1>)
{
    chomp;
    my @result = split(/;/, $_);     # Fix array used here
    $iptv{$result[1]} = $_;         # Fix what's stored here
}
close $in1;

open my $in2, '<', $ARGV[1] or die "Failed to open file $ARGV[1] for reading";
while (<$in2>)
{
    chomp;
    my ($mac, $date) = split(/;/,$_);
    print "$iptv{$mac};$date\n" if (defined $iptv{$mac});
}
close $in2;
```

This uses two file names on the command line and writes to standard output; it is a more general purpose program than your original.  It also gets me around the problem that I don't have a `/home` directory.

For your sample inputs, the output is:

```
8237764738;00:78:9E:EE:CA:6F;FTTH;MULTI;2013/10/28 13:37:50
0415535921;E8:BE:81:86:F1:6F;FTTH;MULTI;2013/11/05 13:38:30
```

You were actually fairly close to this, but were making some silly little mistakes.
In your code, you either aren't showing everything or you aren't using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Perl experts use both to make sure they don't make silly mistakes; beginners should do so too.  It would have pointed out that `@wynik` was not declared with `my` and was assigned to but not used, for example. You could have meant to write `@result = split...;`.  You were not saving the correct data; you were not writing out the information from the `$iptv{$mac}` that you needed to.